# AVL Tree in C, InOrder (and other functions) doesnt work

Tags: c, avl-tree, inorder

Im a newbie at programming and working at an implementation for AVL Trees atm. I got alot of problems and asking for help at 1 of them, maybe I will be able to fix the other ones too after that, since they all sound pretty similiar.

I have the following function for printing the Tree InOrder:

```
void AVL_in_order_walk(AVLTree* avlt)
{
if(avlt!=NULL){
        AVL_in_order_walk(avlt->root->left);
        printf("%d",avlt->root->value);
        AVL_in_order_walk(avlt->root->right);
        }
}
```

Which seems to be pretty wrong. I got following warnings:

```
passing argument 1 of ‘AVL_in_order_walk’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  AVL_in_order_walk(avlt->root->left);
```

I got several errors/warnings/notes like this one. I think I have one big problem simply understanding this: When I have a function like the in_order_walk I posted above, the function doesnt get a node, it gets the whole tree. I alrdy worte a few walks through trees, or insertFunctions, but the function always had a node to start from, because it was called like "void Function(Node* X)".  Now I have the whole tree (AVLTree* avlt) and I dont seem to be able to use recursion because of that, am I wrong?

Btw:
Structs for Tree and Node:

```
struct AVLTree
{
    struct AVLNode* root;
    int numberOfNodes;
};

struct AVLNode
{
    struct AVLNode* left;       
    struct AVLNode* right;  
    struct AVLNode* parent;
    int value;
    int height;
};
```

How its called:

```
void AVL_in_order_walk(AVLTree* avlt);
```

I would really really appreciate any kind of help since I just dont get it..

Comment: `void AVL_in_order_walk(AVLTree* avlt);` That's a function _declaration_, not a function _call_.

Comment: Yes of course that was my bad. I call it in the main with "AVL_in_order_walk(avlt);"

Comment: In your recursive call - AVL_in_order_walk(avlt->root->left);, the argument passed is of type (AVLNode *) while function expects argument of type (AVLTree * ). Same issue for the function call  -  AVL_in_order_walk(avlt->root->right);

Comment: Building an AVL-tree in Pascal was homework during undergraduate coursework. You want to build a red-black trie (unless this is homework).

Answer (score 2):

`void AVL_in_order_walk(AVLTree* avlt)` is declared to accept a `AVLTree*`, but you try to pass it a `AVLNode*`. Your compiler is telling those are pointers to different types.

I suggest you add a hidden function that can be called recursively, and does the actual work.

```
static void AVL_in_order_walk_implementation(AVLNode* avlt) {
  /* Implement the walk */
}

extern void AVL_in_order_walk(AVLTree* avlt) {
   if(avlt)
     AVL_in_order_walk_implementation(avlt->root);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, but how do I call it correctly? No matter what I do, I get 1 billion warnings/errors/...
I see no reason to change something in the main, so Im doing something wrong in those 2 functions I guess, I call it like u wrote it down. Do I have to change something before the "void" ? If I dont I get errors, if I call them "static" and "extern" I get them too..

Comment: @ykykyk - I just noticed something about your code that makes me wonder, are you building your code as C or C++?

Comment: Thats in C, what exactly?

Comment: @ykykyk - No, the code in your question is not valid C. You don't declare the functions correctly, it should be `void AVL_in_order_walk(struct AVLTree* avlt)`. In C, the struct tag (`AVLTree`) doesn't name the type by itself, but it does in C++. So if you are only getting warnings, you are building as C++, not as C.

Comment: @ykykyk-- you should include `typedef`s with your code so we don't have to guess at things that may or may not be in actual code.